# how can I attach another object to the data context in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I have two collections within my app. games and gameDetails. games has a slug defined upon it using the library friendlySlugs, something like: "witcher-3-wild-hunt".

Within my template, I have an `{{#each}}` that has objects/docs from the gameDetails collection that are being looped through. I should note here that I am using publishComposite to also publish the related objects/docs from the games library trough a gameId.

Anyway, within the `{{#each}}` I have a template for each game that contains links through to the single page for that specific game. Here is the problem, The data context is currently set for a gameDetails object and I have to use a db find to access data within the corresponding games object. I want to use the slug within games as the dynamic param for the iron router route like this:

```
this.route('/games/:slug')
```

but first I need to attach the slug to the current data context. Is there any easy way to either extend the data context or run a function within the route to do the db find and access the slug field within the games doc.

Comment: Please format your question. It will be easier to read.

Comment: ^there wasn't much to format since there wanst much code and it was only a paragraph... I did anyway tho and thanks for the downvote.... and might I add nothing considering the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You asked "Is there any easy way to...extend the data context" - the answer is yes. You can use the Transform function (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) to do just that. Once you've done so, you can call functions/derived properties from your data context as if they were part of the original document from your collection.

Here is an example of using it to do something that sounds just like what you're looking for (in this instance, tying Comments information back to the Author collection):
http://dweldon.silvrback.com/models